# How can we better organize Retag-Requests?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sometimes, we have retag requests with hundred/thousands of questions, where the request is sourced in a ambiguous tag synonym. This means some questions can keep the used tag, while other questions need to be retagged.

Since typicaly multiple persons are involved in such a retagging, the questions that doesn't need a retag, are reviewed multiple times. That's because they are still in the tag-list, after one person has reviewed it.

How can we make this more efficient? Do we currently have another workflow, then showing the tag-list?

Comment: You could ask the SOCVR to coordinate, much like they do with burnination requests...

Comment: We recently created [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor) on the auspice of Jon Clements to handle all open burninate, synonym, retag requests and the like. You're welcome to join in.